# Access token key and secret not working in DropNet

Tags: c#, oauth, dropbox, dropnet

I'm using DropNet for Dropbox OAuth but I have one major problem - I can't store access token key and secret cause there is no point storing them. The storing mechanism is not a problem and not a key problem here - the problem is in this:

```
private void dropboxUpload()
{
    DropNetClient _Dclient = new DropNetClient("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", "yyyyyyyyyyyyyyy");
    _Dclient.UseSandbox = true;
    if (!dropboxLoggedIn)
    {
            _Dclient.GetToken();
            string url = _Dclient.BuildAuthorizeUrl();
            Process.Start(url);
            if (MessageBox.Show("Click OK after you have allowed Sizester to create and access a sub-folder called Sizester in a folder called Apps in your Dropbox account.", "Sizester access request", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel) != System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
            {
                return;
            }
        }
        try
        {
            if (!dropboxLoggedIn)
            {
                _Dclient.GetAccessToken();
                dropboxAsecret = _Dclient.UserLogin.Secret;
                dropboxAtoken = _Dclient.UserLogin.Token;
            }
            else
            {
                _Dclient.UserLogin.Token = dropboxAtoken;
                _Dclient.UserLogin.Secret = dropboxAsecret;
            }
            dropboxLoggedIn = true;
            //...
            _Dclient.UploadFile("/", fileE, FileToByteArray(newFilePath));
            MessageBox.Show("Successfully uploaded to Dropbox.", "Uploaded to Dropbox");
        }
        catch (Exception dropboxEx)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error: " + dropboxEx.Message);
        }
    }
```

The problem here is - first time it uploads ok, but the second time it doesn't - although dropboxLoggedIn is true, and access token key and secret are stored ok, it doesn't upload file, but more strangely it doesn't return any error or exception.
If I move GetToken out of if same thing happens. I know I'm doing somewhere wrong, but I can't quite get where.
I've striped some parts of code like file paths and getting the file which are irrelevant.
I did the same thing for Twitter, but it works there with no problems.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so the problem was in initialization of the object - if you do:

```
DropNetClient _Dclient = new DropNetClient("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", "yyyyyyyyyyyyyyy");
_Dclient.UseSandbox = true;
_Dclient.UserLogin.Token = "zzzzzzzzzzzzzzz";
_Dclient.UserLogin.Secret = "wwwwwwwwwwwwww";
```

This wouldn't work - instead it needs to be initialized like this:

```
DropNetClient _Dclient = new DropNetClient("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", "yyyyyyyyyyyyyyy","zzzzzzzzzzzzzzz","wwwwwwwwwwwwww");
_Dclient.UseSandbox = true;
```

I'm not sure where I found the first code sample in some documentation or forum but it's wrong. If you use it - no error or exception will happen, but dropbox file upload or operation won't be done. If you use the second one all will work.

Comment: Ahh, of cource as the UserLogin object would be null at that point. Might add in a helper method to set that instead of using the UserLogin property.

Comment: Am i the only one seeing that the constructor has the wrong argument order? After authorization, when you debut `_client.UserLogin`, it mismatches Secret and Token values. So, debug gives you the incorrect order: what you see in secret actually is token, and what you see in token is secret. This will help you pass the right values in constructor `DropnetClient(consumerKey,consumerSecret,userLogintokenkeyFromDebug,userLoginSecretKeyFromDebug)`

Answer (score 1):

This link should help with that issue:
http://forums.dropbox.com/topic.php?id=61115&replies=6

Basically you need to initialize your `DropNetClient _Dclient` instance out of the Upload File method. When you got access token you should keep it in your session or config file and you won't need to do it every time you upload file.

Comment: That's ok and I did that, but it works only in that instance of an app, but if someone starts another instance of an app, or turns off app and starts it again it won't work (it's a Desktop app). I thought only access key and secret are important and can be saved - anyway that works for twitter (application key and secret are same for every user).

Answer (score 1):

From the looks of that line 3 is messing you up: `if (!dropboxLoggedIn)`

So you are only continuing if the user is not logged in but on the 2nd attempt your saying that should be true, thus skipping all of your upload code.

Comment: But yes best practice would be to initialise a client in the global scope across your entire application and use the same instance for all of your Dropbox functions.

Comment: It formatted the code wrong - as you can see - only the gettoken, build authorize url and process start are called if the client isn't logged in. As for the initializing client - it's not so simple - if another instance of an app is launched as other process it couldn't share the same memory. I haven't had time to answer my question but I found what's wrong - it's the setting of users secret and token.